# How do I handle file change event in Ionic

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a form where I need to attach a file. I am using the `IonInput` component:

```
<IonList>
    <IonItem>
        <IonLabel position="stacked">Select application cover photo</IonLabel>
        <IonInput 
            accept="image/*" 
            type="file" 
            value={application.cover} 
            placeholder="Select application cover photo" 
            name="cover" 
            onIonChange={e => setApplication({
                ...application, 
                cover: e.target.files[0]
            })} 
       /> 
    </IonItem>
</IonList>
```

The selected file is correctly displaying inside of the `IonInput` but when I try to set it to the application state, I get the following error:
`e.target.files is undefined`

I have tried to log out the `target` and as I suspected, the `files` property is not in there. I couldn't find any property where the `files` are stored.
I tried running the same code but with regular `input` instead of `IonInput` and it works as expected.

Here are the versions I am using:

```
"@ionic/react": "^6.0.0",
"@ionic/react-router": "^6.0.0",
```